# How to add metadata to view.raw.php in joomla

Tags: php, joomla

Sorry about my english skill, I only speak very little English

I have ploblem about view.raw.php file in my joomla component

I can't add meta tag or custom tag into this file (i want add meta tag for seo)

How to add metadata to view.raw.php in joomla

example code

```
// Set Facebook metadata
$document->addCustomTag ( '<meta property="og:site_name" content="' . $params_option ['fbsitename'] . '" />' );
$document->addCustomTag ( '<meta property="fb:admins" content="' . $params_option ['fbuser'] . '" />' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try add the code.

$doc =& JFactory::getDocument();

$doc->setMetaData( 'tag-name', 'tag-content' );

Result will be 'meta name="tag-name" content="tag-content" />'.